# I want to send information to google-analytics

Tags: android

I want to send data to google-analytics,Please tell how can I send data to google-analytics in android.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+can+I+send+data+to+google-analytics+in+android).

Comment: you can do it by reading the [google analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get GoogleAnalytics jar.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/resources

Setup your account on google and when your app starts:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide

```
    //Google analytics
    tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    tracker.setDebug(true);
    tracker.startNewSession("UA code",10, this);
```

To track (event for example):

```
tracker.trackEvent("landing.login", "tap", "login", 0);
```